# Using the sicktoolbox_wrapper with LMS1xx

Tags: ros, lidar, sicklms, sicktoolbox-wrapper, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect an LMS111 through my computer's ethernet port, and use it with the sicktoolbox_wrapper.  Will the package work properly with an LMS1xx?  Are there any changes to the tutorial steps I need to do, particularly concerning the permission configuration to the ethernet port (eth1 in my case), in order to make it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66437/using-the-sicktoolbox_wrapper-with-lms1xx/) by [gpuszko](https://answers.ros.org/users/5306/gpuszko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For for LMS1xx Series I think the driver is here [LMS1xx driver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/LMS1xx). I have used the driver package with SICK LMS100.

The command for running the driver after connecting it via Ethernet is

```
rosrun LMS1xx LMS100 _host:=192.168.0.1
```

where 192.168.0.1 is the IP of the Laser-scanner(I think IP I used is the default one, not sure though). Change it according to your IP settings.

---

Originally posted by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) with karma: 172 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-06-30**:
Hello, I am in the same situation as the person who asked this question, and tried your solution (I had to modify if to the following: rosrun lms1xx LMS100.launch _host:=(my_ip_adress) in order for it to say it could find the files and stuff).

However, now I am getting the error:
cannot launch node of type [LMS1xx/LMS1xx_node]: LMS1xx
ros path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ros path[1]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ros path[2]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
no processes to monitor

ANy idea what could be going wrong?  Thanks,

Randyh

**Comment by [DavidSuh](https://answers.ros.org/users/3574/davidsuh/) on 2014-08-26**:
Has anyone made this work?